# I have a <tag input > field and I am trying to disable that tag on condition. But not able to do with reactive forms my code is as follows

Tags: angular

I have a  field and I am trying to disable that tag on condition. But not able to do with reactive forms my code is as follows

.html file

```
<tag-input formControlName="externalLinkItems" name="externalLinkItems" class="w-100"
            ngbTooltip="Press enter to add multiple parameters" placement="top" (onAdd)="addExternalLinkParameters()"
            (onRemove)="removeExternalLinkParameters($event)"></tag-input>
```

.ts

```
 this.addSetupForm.controls.externalLinkItems.disable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `tag-input` is a custom component. Please make sure it is a "Control". And in that control `disable` is handled.

```
  setDisabledState(disabled: boolean) {
    this.disabled = disabled;
  }
```

[Reference](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/)